# How to throttle bandwidth for OverGrive in Linux (Debian)?

Tags: linux, bandwidth-throttling, trickle

I've installed trickle but can't seem to get it to throttle overGrive.

```
$ trickle -d 500 -u 100 overgrive
trickle: Could not reach trickled, working independently: No such file or directory
trickle: exec(): No such file or directory
```

Is there another way to get overGrive to stop sucking up all my bandwidth while syncing?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem? I just realized this and I had to turn it off, since it uploads up to the 7GB of data each day. One option might be to turn off AutoSync option, but it would be great if there is some better solution.

Comment: Crap sorry, thought I replied to this ages ago.  I never did find a solution to this and to make things worse, I had a symlink of my google drive dir in my google drive dir that OverDrive followed and also synced... recursively... so it basically just filled up my account with copies and copies of my stuff. lol

Comment: I solved my issue and described what helped me in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue I had and my overGrive works fine for the last couple of weeks. It turned out that it had synchronized with some public files created by different users, and which didn't have anything in common with my Google Drive account. What was common for all these files is that it belonged to some courses and had names like: "MATH&141, Mod 01: Quiz 2 Toolkit". For some reason these files didn't have .doc extension and had symbols & and : in names, which seems to cause overGrive stack on it forever.
Anyway, I did perfom the following steps and it fixed the issue:

- downloaded and installed the latest version of overgrive.
- clear all trash files from Google Drive online
- delete all files from your local Google Drive folder if present and restart overGrive:

  - .overgrive.lastsync
  - .overgrive.cache
- turn off automatic sync, and start synchronization manually.
- wait until full synchronization is finished.

You can check in your Home folder log file called .overgrive.log to see if there are some errors during the synchronization. It might happen that overGrive blocks on some specific file and try to synchronize it over and over again causing large use of download/upload.